# NAudio - Get Wav Peak Data as Int16 Values

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, audiowaveform

I want to use NAudio to extract the peak values of wav audio files like the *audiowaveform* library provides. Which is an array of short values like:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "channels": 2,
  "sample_rate": 48000,
  "samples_per_pixel": 512,
  "bits": 8,
  "length": 3,
  "data": [-65,63,-66,64,-40,41,-39,45,-55,43,-55,44]
}
```

https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform/blob/master/doc/DataFormat.md

I saw that NAudio has a built-in WaveformRenderer that outputs png images, but I just need the raw peak data. Built-in NAudio classes like MaxPeakProvider (which is initialized with waveReader.ToSampleProvider()) etc works with floats, I need them as short values. Is it possible?

**Edit after @Blindy's response**

I have this piece of code, converting peak data to shorts, but it produces slightly wrong values when comparing with the output of audiowaveform. What might be the problem? I guess there is a data type conversion or rounding error?

```
        var waveReader = new WaveFileReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        var wave = new WaveChannel32(waveReader);

        var peakProvider = new MaxPeakProvider();

        int bytesPerSample = (waveReader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8);
        var samples = waveReader.Length / bytesPerSample;

        int pixelsPerPeak = 1;
        int spacerPixels = 0;

        var samplesPerPixel = 32; 
        var stepSize = pixelsPerPeak + spacerPixels;
        peakProvider.Init(waveReader.ToSampleProvider(), samplesPerPixel * stepSize);
        List<short> resultValuesAsShort = new List<short>();
        List<float> resultValuesAsFloat= new List<float>();

        PeakInfo currentPeak = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < samples / samplesPerPixel; i++)
        {
            currentPeak = peakProvider.GetNextPeak();

            resultValuesAsShort.Add((short)(currentPeak.Min * short.MaxValue));
            resultValuesAsShort.Add((short)(currentPeak.Max * short.MaxValue));

            //resultValuesAsFloat.Add(currentPeak.Min);
            //resultValuesAsFloat.Add(currentPeak.Max);
        }
```

Here are the results comparison:

[image]

**Edit2:** Examining further, I noticed that it is generating quite different results for the latter values than *audiowaveform* library and I don't have any idea for the reason:

[image]

Comment: Should have commented on my response, I didn't see your edit. First thing I would try is to multiply the `float` value by `short.MaxValue` and keep it as a `float`, and then look at the decimal points. It could be as easy as adding a `MathF.Round` and rounding away from zero.

Comment: Either way, the difference seems to be at most 1 unit, out of 65535. That's a 0.00001525902 error (if it's indeed an error). I wouldn't waste a second of my time on that kind of number.

Comment: Hi @Blindy, actually it is producing quite different results than audiowaveform, if you may look at my latest edit on the post.

Answer (score 1):

> MaxPeakProvider [...] works with floats, I need them as short values

NAudio in general works with floats, it's just how it was designed. To get the 2-byte short representation, multiply each `float` by `short.MaxValue` (the floats are in the `[-1..1]` range).